# How can I change the position of an item in ListView dynamically in android

Tags: android, listview

I have created a dynamic ListView which contains 4 Buttons what I want is on pressing a button, that button containing row should shift to first position in ListView.
How can I do this? Please Help Me Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Just change order of items in adapter and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

and you have to do it from UI thread.